# Save which image a user selected iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, image, swift, uiimageview

I have a profile tab in my app. When I open the tab I see the normal image.
It is possible to select a image from the camera roll.
Code:

```
 func selectImage()
    {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary){

            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

            self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

When a user selects a image it is set to the imageView

```
       func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in

            })
            userImage.image = image

        }
```

How can i save this image for the next time the user opens the apps?
I only found a SO question which used NSUserDefaults but they said this was not recommend.

Is saving the filepath better? if so, how can i manage that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to save image to file path use the following code

```
let fileDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    .DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in

        })
        userImage.image = image
        var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
        var imageFilePath = fileDirectory[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("userPicture.jpeg")
        var imageFileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imageFilePath)
        imageData.writeToURL(imageFileURL!, atomically: false)
}
```

In order to set image from your saved local file you have to first check if that file exist then load its content to image view

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

var imagePath = fileDirectory[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("userPicture.jpeg")

var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    if (fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(imagePath)){

            userImage.image =  UIImage(contentsOfFile : imagePath)

    }
}
```